# Questions about Big O Notation of Recursive Bisection Search

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I was following this Python course held by MIT (6.0001 Fall 2016) and during one of his lectures, the professor described the function which returns `True` if an element (e) is in a list (L), `False` otherwise:

```
def bisect_search1(L, e):
    if L == []:
        return False
    
    elif len(L) == 1:
        return L[0] == e
    
    else:
        half = len(L)//2
        if L[half] > e:
            return bisect_search1(L[:half], e)
        else:
            return bisect_search1(L[half:], e)
```

Going on to the next lecture slide, I understand that bisection search calls are O(log n) complexity because the input is to be halved every loop or call.

What I still don't understand from the slide are these points:

- O(n) for each bisection search call to copy list, **this is the cost to set up each call, so do this for each level of recursion**
- If we are really careful, note that the length of the list to be copied is also halved on each recursive call, **turns out that the total cost to copy is O(n) and this dominates the log n cost due to the recursive calls**

Things that I still don't understand are:

1. Does slicing part of a list and copying a whole list have the same big O complexity O(n)?
2. If yes, I understand why the function has O(n log n) complexity. But what does this "**turns out that the total cost to copy is O(n) and this dominates the log n cost due to the recursive calls**" even mean? Does that mean the function now has O(n) complexity?

I'm sorry if a similar question had been asked before and seems to be beginnerish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Taking a list slice has the cost O(m) where m is the size of the slice. This is because it has to create a new list of size m and populate its entries.
2. On the first call, the slice is of size n/2. Inside the first recursive call, the slice taken is now of size n/4. And it continues to be reduced by 1/2 on each recursive call.The total cost of taking slices is therefore:  O(n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...) = O(n)  (by taking the sum of the geometric series).

Comment: Thank you!. For the second point, that was my first thought, but the ```half``` variable uses integer division(//) so I'm not sure if it's really a geometric series.

Comment: @yfr The inaccuracies introduced by the integer division are small enough that they don't change the big-O.  You can make this calculation more formal (and more complicated). For example, take N = the next power of 2 larger than n. You can then show that the solution is O(N/2+N/4+...)=O(N)=O(n).

Comment: Thank you for elaborating! Say, hypothetically instead of slicing half the list, I copied the whole list. Does that mean O(n + n + n + ...) = O(n), and the function still would be O(n log n) complexity?

Comment: @yfr If you performed n steps in each recursive call where n is the original list size then the total would be O(n logn). But if you performed n steps where n is the size of the list passed to the recursive call, it would still be O(n) total (I'm assuming the list size still decreases by half somehow, because otherwise you'd have infinite recursion).

Comment: I think I understand it better now. @PaulHankin explanation's also makes it clearer. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Slicing a list takes time proportional to the length of the slice. If you have a list of size n, and are slicing half of it, the time is proportional to n/2 and hence O(n).

The quote from the professor about the cost of copying dominating the cost of the recursive calls is just saying that normally a bisection search would be O(log n) -- the depth of the recursive calls -- but here there's also some copying, some of which take O(n) time. You can use these words to justify O(n log n) as an upper bound, but they don't justify the exact complexity (which is in fact O(n) because the amount copied halves each time).